# Marshal.GetActiveObject() problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I am using

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcelApp = 
                     (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

in my project.  It gives me an error when there is no Excel file open at the moment.  How can I check to see if there is no Excel file running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject.aspx) of using Marshal.GetActiveObject and how to handle situation if object not found. Hope this will help.